# Trying to log into the superset postgress example database - need password

Tags: postgresql, apache-superset

I am trying to log in with an sql editor to the database named example that comes with superset when you run it through docker.  I believe I am connecting to the database properly using the ip (doesn't work with localhost) but don't have the username and password

I have tried the following username and password combinations

admin admin

superset_user password

root root

UserName DBPassword

superset_user DBPassword

I do not know the password to login.  Does anyone know the password

Answer (score 5):

Please try this,

DATABASE_PORT=5432

POSTGRES_DB=superset

POSTGRES_USER=superset

POSTGRES_PASSWORD=superset

SQLALCHEMY URI:

postgresql://superset:superset@db:5432/superset

Answer (score 0):

Okay if you want to connect postgresql example database you can create free database in [here](https://dashboard.render.com/)

It takes 2 min to create. Then you can just copy *External Database URL* it gives SQLALCHEMY URL Directly.

[image]